# Multi match in re2 regex for terraform

Tags: regex, terraform

I'm trying to apply regex in something like this, in terraform.

```
variable "version" {
   type        = "string"
   default     = https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/item-v1.2/item-item2-v1.2.gz
   description = "version"
}

name = "${replace(var.version, "//", "")}"
```

I just need to replace everything and output only "v1.2" for the name, specifically from the `item-v1.2` file path. I was thinking of doing something along the lines of

```
name = "${replace(var.version, "//", "")}"
```

wherein I replace everything but v1.2.

Any idea how to do it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this the `v1.2` in the path, i.e. `item-v1.2` or the one from the gz, i.e. `item-item2-v1.2.gz`?

Comment: it's the v1.2 in the path, sorry for not clarifying! @yvesonline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your variable definition (e.g. wrong use of quotes, variable name "version" is reserved due to its special meaning inside module blocks, and so on) so I operate on the following:

```
variable "my_version" {
    type        = string
    default     = "https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/item-v1.2/item-item2-v1.2.gz"
    description = "version"
}
```

Then you can extract the version (or replace everything else except the version as requested) from the sub-folder path like this (this has been run and tested with `terraform console`):

```
$ terraform console
> var.my_version
"https://s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/bucket/folder/item-v1.2/item-item2-v1.2.gz"
> regex(".*-(.*)/.*.gz", var.my_version)[0]
"v1.2"
> replace(var.my_version, "/.*-(.*)/.*.gz/", "<before> $1 <after>")
"<before> v1.2 <after>"
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It definitely does work, but I would like to get the one in the file path instead, like the folder `item-v1.2` before `item-item2-v1.2.gz`. How should it look like, if ever?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to do it in a replace kind of way? i.e `name = "${replace(var.my_version, "/<regex here>/", "text that replaces everything but v1.2")}"`